# Sending the selected jQuery tab index to rails controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using jQuery tabs in my rails view. When a tab is selected accordingly something should happen at rails server side.

Selected tab can be found from the following code :

```
$('#tabs').tabs( {
   select : function(event,ui){
             tabnumber = ui.index; }})
```

Now, how can I pass this to my rails controller? I guess jQuery ajax can be used. But since my new to web development, I am not able to figure out much.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've covered this before [over here at this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830352/how-to-pass-data-from-jquery-to-controller).

Basically, construct ajax object as normal.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/my/controller',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {tabnumber : tabnumber},
    success: function(data){
        //whatever you respond back with is the data here
    }
});
```

Then in your RoR controller..

```
def process
    var tab_number = params[:tab_number]
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !!! I tried this but I cannot see the output .My success function is 
function(data) {$("text").append(data);}
But I cannot see the data appended on the div's HTML