# AJAX request to Rails Controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

To begin, my knowledge of routes and controllers are limited.

I have a controller:

```
class FeedbackController < ApplicationController
end
```

I have an AJAX request that captures values. I want to post that data back to the controller but I am unsure what to do with the controller. AJAX REQUEST:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit_button", function() {
  var dataVals, data_value_selector, star_value_selector;
  var data_value_selector = $(".tag_clone").attr("data-value");
  var star_value_selector = $('.star_selected').val();
  var dataVals = $('.selectize-input.items.not-full').children('.tag_clone').map(function() {
    return $(this).data("value");
  }).get();
if (data_value_selector !== void 0 && (star_value_selector !== void 0)) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/feedback/create",   <-----This is where I'm confused
    data: {
      hashtag_library: dataVals,
      star_value: star_value_selector
    }
  });
}
```

});

All I want to do with the data right now is console log it with the controller, is that possible?

Comment: Have you defined the url /feedback/create in your routes file? This is necessary before you can make a POST request to it. In addition to the route to the method you wish to call, you need to write the method itself! Your controller seems to be empty.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I did not define the url /feedback/create in my routes file. Would I just do something along the lines of: get feedback/create => 'feedback#create'?

Then, in my controller, def create? Would I need params to capture the data being sent?

Comment: Yes, but you want a post not get.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. The console logging of data would just take place in my create method then, right?

def create
console.log(data)
end

Something like that?

Comment: You can't use `console.log` in your controller, but, you could use a debugger instead. Furthermore, you can display the data returned by your create action in the view (within your AJAX function): `...success: function(response) { console.log(response); }`.

Comment: Yes, when you do the post to the method, it will execute all of the code inside that method. For Ruby, you use puts instead of console.log. See this question for an example of what the whole thing might look like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830352/how-to-pass-data-from-jquery-to-controller

Comment: Ahh perfect, thanks so much. Totally makes sense now...

Comment: What Kyle is writing is so wrong I have no words to describe it. Don't create any route for `feedback/create`. Just POST to `/feedbacks`. And you should probably rather use query-ujs instead of your code.

Comment: Also, watch this RailsCast, it should clear up a lot of things for you http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: Ah, I just realised your controller is called `Feedback`. Is there any reason it's a singular resource? (not following Rails convention)

Comment: Thanks Michal. I am going to watch that railscasts right now.

I just did a resources: Feedback and it generated this controller for me. Should it be called something else???

Comment: Michal, can you explain why you think posting to feedback/create is wrong?

Comment: Also, feedback as a name is following rails convention--because feedback can be plural.